# AutoMapper - Mapping Complex Lists and Dictionaries of System.Object

Tags: automapper

I have the following classes and I need to map an Agent to an AgentDto.

```cs
public class ObjectsAddedToCollectionProperties : Dictionary<string, ObjectList> {}

public class OriginalValuesDictionary : Dictionary<string, Object> {}

public class ObjectChangeTracker()
{
  public ObjectsAddedToCollectionProperties ObjectsAddedToCollectionProperties { get; set; }
  public OriginalValuesDictionary OriginalValues { get; set; }
}

public class BaseDto
{
  public ObjectChangeTracker ChangeTracker { get; set; }
}

public class RolesDto : BaseDto {}

public class AgentDto : BaseDto 
{
   ICollection<RoleDto> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class ModelBase
{
  public ObjectChangeTracker ChangeTracker { get; set; }
}

public class Role : ModelBase {}

public class Agent : ModelBase 
{
   ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my mapper configuration

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Agent, AgentDto>().IgnoreAllNonExisitng();
Mapper.CreateMap<Role, RoleDto>().IgnoreAllNonExisitng();

var agent = new Agent();
Mapper.Map<AgentDto>(agent);
```

When I map Agent to AgentDto Roles are correctly mapped but anything I add to one of the Dictionaries isn't mapped. I assume this is because AutoMapper has no way of telling what the destination type should be and because the destination type is an Object it infers that it can simply copy the source object.

I've created a custom resolver but for some reason it isn't being called

```cs
class ChangeTrackerResolver : ValueResolver<ObjectChangeTracker, ObjectChangeTracker>
    {
        protected override ObjectChangeTracker ResolveCore(ObjectChangeTracker source)
        {
            var typeMap = Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps();

            var destination = new ObjectChangeTracker();

            foreach (var keyValuePairs in source.ObjectsAddedToCollectionProperties)
            {
                var objectList = new ObjectList();
                objectList.AddRange(from value in keyValuePairs.Value
                                    let sourceType = value.GetType()
                                    let destinationType = typeMap.Where(map => map.SourceType == sourceType).Single().DestinationType
                                    select Mapper.Map(value, sourceType, destinationType));

                destination.ObjectsAddedToCollectionProperties.Add(keyValuePairs.Key, objectList);
            }

            foreach (var keyValuePairs in source.ObjectsRemovedFromCollectionProperties)
            {
                var objectList = new ObjectList();
                objectList.AddRange(from value in keyValuePairs.Value
                                    let sourceType = value.GetType()
                                    let destinationType = typeMap.Where(map => map.SourceType == sourceType).Single().DestinationType
                                    select Mapper.Map(value, sourceType, destinationType));

                destination.ObjectsRemovedFromCollectionProperties.Add(keyValuePairs.Key, objectList);
            }

            foreach (var keyValuePairs in source.OriginalValues)
            {
                var sourceType = keyValuePairs.Value.GetType();
                var destinationType = typeMap.Where(map => map.SourceType == sourceType).Single().DestinationType;
                destination.OriginalValues.Add(keyValuePairs.Key, Mapper.Map(keyValuePairs.Value, sourceType, destinationType));
            }

            foreach (var keyValuePairs in source.ExtendedProperties)
            {
                var sourceType = keyValuePairs.Value.GetType();
                var destinationType = typeMap.Where(map => map.SourceType == sourceType).Single().DestinationType;
                destination.ExtendedProperties.Add(keyValuePairs.Key, Mapper.Map(keyValuePairs.Value, sourceType, destinationType));
            }

            return destination;
        }
    }
```

And this is my mapping

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<ModelBase, BaseDto>()
                .Include<Agent, AgentDto>()
                .Include<Address, AddressDto>()
                .Include<BankAccount, BankAccountDto>()
                .Include<Client, ClientDto>()
                .Include<Person, PersonDto>()
                .Include<Role, RoleDto>()
                .Include<TelephoneNumber, TelephoneNumberDto>()
                .Include<Height, HeightDto>()
                .Include<Weight, WeightDto>()
                .IgnoreAllNonExisitng().ForMember(
                a => a.ChangeTracker,
                opt => opt.ResolveUsing<ChangeTrackerResolver>());
```

EDIT

I've fixed the problem with my mapping and my Resolver is now getting called but objects in the Dictionaries e.g ObjectsAddedToCollectionProperties are not present in the ChangeTracker passed to the Resolver. Here is my new mapping.

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Agent, AgentDto>()
                .IgnoreAllNonExisitng().ForMember(
                a => a.ChangeTracker,
                opt => opt.ResolveUsing<ChangeTrackerResolver>().FromMember(a => a.ChangeTracker));
```

Comment: Why are you including the change tracker on your DTO? For assignable types - that is types on both sides are the same, and you haven't done CreateMap, it will assign. At least in 3.0 now.

Comment: The change tracker tracks changes on the client side to my business objects i.e. Agent which I then need to reply on the server-side against the DTOs. Change tracker deals with objects because it can contain a mixture of business objects and primitive types i.e. Agent, Role, ints. I need to map any business objects in the change tracker to their DTO equivalents.